# Tags Protractor + Jasmine to run set of suites

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, cucumberjs

I'm trying to figure out a way to use in the same way, or better said, similar way, the tagging options that `cucumberJS` has with `protractor`, but with `Jasmin`e, is there a way to tag the different scenarios, like: `@smoke`, `@regression`, etc.. and then tell on console to run with those?

I'm declining to use `Cucumber`, since it's support it's seems to be getting flaky!

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 10):

With jasmine2 you can filter tests using a regular expression. Maybe you can add something like @smoke, @regressions to your tests and then only run those ones by passing the grep flag:

```
it('should do stuff @smoke', function() {
  ...
});
```

Then run protractor passing the grep flag:

`protractor conf.js --grep='@smoke'`

Comment: Andres, How about the same comment that I placed below to Alecxe? how would the grep behave, if I tag with 2 o more tags? like, " .... @smoke @feature1..." could I filter then with: '--grep=@smoke, @feature1'? or it will execute the test twice?

Comment: I tried with --grep= '@smoke', '@regression' but it doesn't work is there any way we can execute multiple tags?

Answer (score 7):

Alternative to `grep` would to be to use [`suites`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/2bde92b3e745e09ad3876932b2d187365e9aaa31/spec/suitesConf.js):

```
suites: {
    smoke: [ 
        "spec1.js",
        "spec2.js",
        "spec3.js"
    ],

    regression: [
        "spec4.js",
        "spec5.js",
    ],
}
```

Then, run protractor specifying the `suite` argument:

```
protractor conf.js --suite smoke
protractor conf.js --suite regression
protractor conf.js --suite smoke,regression
```

Comment: thanks, but, how about if I want to run isolated 'spec1.js' from the smoke suite? what do you think about having another collection inside smoke: like, 'suites: { smoke: [ feature1: "spec1.js" ...' to be run later like: 'protractor conf.js --suite feature1' is this possible? in case you think its not, what would you suggest?

Comment: @BrunoSoko have not tested that, but not sure if it's gonna work: `suites: {smoke: {feature1: ["spec1.js"], feature2: ["spec2.js"]}}`. Then, you may try running them as `--suites smoke.feature1`. Alternatively, you can run the specs directly via `--specs`..

Answer (score 0):

**Running protractor tests with multiple tags in using jasmine framework:**

protractor.conf.js --grep '@smoke|@regression'

Comment: How does this improve on the existing answers?

Comment: instead of using suites we can use the command that i mentioned, it seems few folks tried to run multiple tags with grep and failed so i shared this one