# Tagging Protractor - Jasmine e2e Tests for execution

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor, ui-automation, angular-e2e

I have written some e2e UI tests for an angular 6 app using protractor and jasmine. I am looking to see how I can tag specific "It"s for execution. I want to be able to tag them as @smoke, @ regression etc.

How can this be achieved ? I run my tests with ng e2e.

Comment: Not exactly tagging, but may come in handy:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34004522/tags-protractor-jasmine-to-run-set-of-suites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized you can exclude tests from execution by marking them as xit. Jasmine also give s you fit if you need to run a test first.

```
describe('test to be excluded from execution', ()= > {

xit('Test 1', () => {
   code to be run

  });

fit('Test 2', () => {
   code to be run

  });

 it('Test 3', () => {
   code to be run

  });

});
```

Tests will run in the order

Test 2
Test 3

Answer (score 0):

Use below configuration in conf.js file

```
suites: {
            smoke: ['./smoke/*.spec.js'],
            regression: ['./regression/*.spec.js'],
            functional: ['./functional/*.spec.js'],
            all: ['./*/*.spec.js'],
           selected: ['./functional/addcust.spec.js','./regression/openacc.spec.js'],
    }
```

The way to run them is as shown below single suite or multiple suite run

```
protractor conf.js --suite=selected 
protractor conf.js --suite=smoke,regression
```

Just to add on there is one more way of not executing a selected test case - [not recommended] i.e. using xit instead of it. This is also a jasmine keyword.

```
describe('test login as admin',function(){
**xit**('login as admin', function(){
page.navigateToURL("http://angularjs-protractor/");
expect(page.getPageTitle()).toBe('Protractor App');
expect(browser.getTitle()).equals('Title');
browser.sleep(3000);
});
});
```